# Called Delegate Method after Stopping Recording Video

Tags: swift, avcapture, avcapturemoviefileoutput

When I stop recording video manually, using `stopRecording()` method of an instance of `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, it will call `fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)` delegate method of `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`. But when I stop video automatically using `maxRecordedDuration`, the `captureOutput(captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:)` delegate method will be called, that I couldn't find this method documentation on developer.apple.com website.

Also there is another method `capture(_:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt:fromConnections:error:)`.

On `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` documentation there is only `fileOutput` methods and there is nothing about `captureOutput` or `capture` methods.

Is there a method that I handle the output file in it and will be called in any situations? so that I can handle the output in just one method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure though it may be swift-api translation error. Some AVFoundation API have strange obj-c to swift api assignment.

From header file AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate has:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)output didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray<AVCaptureConnection *> *)connections error:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

Swift api counterpart is:

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, 
       didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, 
       from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], 
      error: Error?)
```

I noticed both are different from your comment. Swift api correction may occure on SDK update. I recommend you to check SDK directory if it is SDK error.